# Libgdx game closes after some time being played

Tags: android, libgdx

I have developed an Android game using Libgdx. It is like a Flappy Bird. 
I have one screen with 4 stages.

```
gameStage = new GameStage(viewport, true);
hudStage = new HudStage();
menuBeginStage = new MenuBeginStage();
menuEndStage = new MenuEndStage(this);
```

When the player hits the wall, the menuEndStage is triggered and this menu has only one button to restart the game.

Once the button is pressed I dispose every resource of every stage and finally I set again a new screen, so the game begins.

```
mainScreen = new MainScreen(firstGame);
setScreen(mainScreen);
```

The problem I have is that when I play for maybe 10 minutes without finishing the process of my game in Android, the game is rendered slower until the game is suddenly closed. I don't know why is this happening. I suposse it is a memory problem but I don't know the reason because I am disposing every resource in all the stages when the player hits the wall and the game begins again.
Any reasons why this could be happening?

Comment: are you creating new objects in your render method? If that's the case gradually you will run out of memory

Comment: @george I create doors dinamically inside the render method, but I create them when the player for croses 10 doors, I dinamically add 10 more but I do not create a new instance every render iteration. Aren't that instances supossed to be clear by the garbage collector when I restart the screen?

Comment: You are definitely doing something bad like allocating new objects every render(). I would look into running a profiler on your code. Google 'eclipse profiler' and download one. I once had a similar issue so I ran a profiler and it told me exactly which line was bad. Either that or go through your code line by line making sure you're not new'ing up objects somewhere you shouldn't be.

Comment: @Barodapride thank you, I didn't know there was such tool available. Let's see if I find the problem using a profiler.

Comment: @Juan Manuel Amoros. Don't create new objects but reuse them if you can and your problem will be solved

Comment: Libgdx does load some stuff natively that won't get picked up by the GC. For any object that implements Disposable, you must call `dispose` on it before it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm doing so, except some textures that I defined static because I didn't want to have lots of instances of the same Texture. I am going to define them as attributes of the instance and not of the class maybe the problem is that.

Answer (score 1):

You have for sure problem with you asset managment - you should monitor your app's RAM usage - I'm pretty sure it is critical after some time.

You should always **dispose** your assets - take a look at [list of entities you have to dispose](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management).

In fact the best you can do is to use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) - it is special class that will handle the load/dispose thing.

From my experience - do not dispose assets if it is not necessary - why would you dispose a texture if you have to load it a second after? **What has changed in the texture during this time?** You should

- Reset your bodies'es positions
- Reset your fields with points count etc...

but not dispose assets - load them **once in show method** (using AssetManager ;) ) and do not care about them when resetting level.

Comment: I'm using Box2D Lights, I forgot to dispose the rayHandler. Now I have disposed() every asset that I load. In the dispose() method I also set every object to null (Lets see if the garbage collector works better). Even though, watching the memory allocated in the monitor it increases faster than the collector collects the garbage.